# PathIterator for java.awt.Rectangle always gives (0,0)

Tags: java, affinetransform, path-iterator

In my code, I create an instance of *`java.awt.Rectangle` with a corner and length and width*. Then I *apply a rotation affine transformation*(at) on it to rotate it by a certain angle.

Then I fetch rectangle's PathIterator and iterate the geometry as:

```
PathIterator i = rectangle.getPathIterator(at);
while (!i.isDone()) {
    double[] xy = new double[2];
    i.currentSegment(xy);
}
```

While I expect 4 points(or 5 as first and last may be same), what I get is 6 points. And more surprising is that last point is always (0,0).
(0,0) is not part of rectangle geometry, but I still get it always.
What is the reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value of `currentSegment`. The last "point" will be of type `PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE`, which is documented as:

> The segment type constant that specifies that
>   the preceding subpath should be closed by appending a line segment
>   back to the point corresponding to the most recent SEG_MOVETO.

The point data associated with this type is implicit (i.e. the first and last points in the path). Nothing is written to the array when `currentSegment` returns `SEG_MOVETO`; the point (0, 0) you're seeing on the last call is the value that the array was initialised with when you created it.

Comment: "the data it places in the array should be ignored." Can you please explain this?